# Is WCF threading model different from the old ASMX service threading model?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, wcf, web-services

ASMX runs just like you'd access a web page use/reuse IIS thread. What about WCF ? Do I get a different instance & thread(old or new is irrelevant)  per request (assume no session) ?

Comment: No session and no singleton means: per-call activation of your service class. The WCF runtime will grab a thread from the threadpool and assign it to handle your request. WCF is by default *not* tightly integrated into the ASP.NET runtime - it can be living totally without IIS and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

WCF is more configurable than ASMX, and may run in hosts other than IIS.

I think you can assume that threads will come from the thread pool.

Instancing will be controlled by the configured [InstanceContextMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.instancecontextmode.aspx) of the service.

Re-entrancy is controlled by the configured [ConcurrencyMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.concurrencymode.aspx) of the service.